# Finding two values in a column and calculating difference of adjacent cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I’ve two columns as follows.

[image]

```
A              B            C
1   1/9/2016  12:57:48 PM       Text A  
2   1/9/2016 1:04:48 PM     Text A  
3   1/9/2016 1:05:04 PM     Text A  
4   1/9/2016 1:05:14 PM     Text A  
5   1/9/2016 1:05:15 PM     Text B      A5 – A1
6   1/9/2016 1:05:38 PM     Text A  
7   1/11/2016 9:57:12 AM        Text A  
8   1/15/2016 10:42:55 AM       Text A  
9   1/15/2016 10:45:21 AM       Text B      A9 – A6
10  1/15/2016 10:58:12 AM       Text A
```

Query: 
I need the difference of Cell: A5 & Cell: A1 in the cell C5, A9 – A6 in C9 and so on.. 
So basically, we have to look at the Column B for a change in the text value – and subtract the corresponding  column A values. Hope my explanation of the problem is understandable. If not – do let me know. I can help to understand in a better way if possible.

Comment: Can you use the `DATEDIF` function to work out the difference in cells C5 and C9, then drag down? Excel should figure out the pattern you want.

Comment: @JayF1, excel definitely won't work out that pattern. It's dependent on when TextA-->TextB and vica versa in column B

Answer (score 1):

Could you use one more column? if so the solution may look like this:

let D be additional column

- in D1 put formula: =A1
- in D2 put formula: =IF(B1="Text B", A2, D1)

  - drag down formula from D2
- in C2 put formula: =IF(B2="Text B", A2-D1, "")

  - drag down formula from C2

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 small changes to the C2 formula in @Agata Powalka's answer, which is good:

```
=IF(B2 = "Text B", IF(B1 = "Text B", A2, A2-D2), "")
```

This handles the case when a `Text B` row occurs immediately below another, where it will display whatever's in column `A`. I also changed `A2-D1` to `A2-D2` just for clarity; it doesn't change the results.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, it's a bit tricky but can be done with formulae only. I Assumed there's no header and text to find is `'B'`, and `A:A` is date and `B:B` is text. Add a column `D` and set `D1` to below:

```
=index(
   $A:$A, 
   index(
     transpose(split("1 "&join(" ", arrayformula(if($B:$B="B", row($B:$B), ""))), " ")), 
     countif($B$1:$B1, "B"), 
     1
   )
 )
```

Above formula will result the last date which has text `'B'`. Now copy `D1` and drag down. Now result column `C` is trivial. Type below on `C1` and drag down.

```
=if(B1="B", A1-D1, "")
```

Sample file is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PfVUgBYw9XDto6-CSf3MezzhQgaOLJokGaBXJTTX9G8/) and below is its screenshot. I set the format of column `C` to `duration` and emphasized some dates on column `A`.

[image]

If you prefer custom function or running a script, dozens line of GAS can do this job too. Personally, I prefer formulae, even if it's kind of ugly.